# Display Persian/Arabic text with VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, farsi

When I run the macro with

```
slideObject.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "نوشته من"
```

It displays a text with weird characters. What is the way to fix it? I have my system locale set to Persian (Iran).
"[image]"

Any help would be much appreciated.